# fatal error: when my PFUser object is unwrapped

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Hi I am trying to show the user's score in a label.  I have told it what to do whenever the object is nil but for some reason it still has an error when the label loads. How do I fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
    let score: AnyObject? = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("score")

        self.SpotScore.text = ("Spot Score: " + (score! as! String))
        if score == nil{

            self.SpotScore.text = ("Spot Score: Create or Go to a Spot!")
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *optional binding* to check for `nil`:

```
if let score = PFUser.currentUser()?["score"] as? String {
    self.SpotScore.text = "Spot Score: \(score)"
} else {
    self.SpotScore.text = "Spot Score: Create or Go to a Spot!"
}
```

or you could use the *nil-coalescing operator* `??` to create the `score` string:

```
let score = (PFUser.currentUser()?["score"] as? String) ?? "Create or Go to a Spot!"
self.SpotScore.text = "Spot Score: " + score
```